# cx_freezer with subroutine

Tags: python, cx-freeze, subroutine

I have a problem, I have a python script that runs just fine when I run it, but I'm trying to create an executable it crashes.

## setup.py

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import os 

os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = r'C:\Users\x_sal\Anaconda3\tcl\tcl8.6'
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = r'C:\Users\x_sal\Anaconda3\tcl\tk8.6'

build_exe_options = {"packages": [
    "os",
    "sys",
    "matplotlib",
    "subprocess",
    "serial",
    "numpy",
    "msvcrt",
    "time",
    "dataCollectionE"
    ]}

setup(
    name = "Data Collection",
    version = "1",
    description = "Read data from Arduino",
    options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
    executables = [Executable("dataCollection.py")])
```

## dataCollection.py

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    fid = fileN()
    dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0])))
    cmdline = 'python -c "from dataCollection import printSerial; printSerial() "'
    rc = call("start cmd /K " + cmdline, cwd=dir, shell=True) # run `cmdline` in `dir`
    while fid == fileN():
        time.sleep(1)
    livePlot(dados = "f")
```

livePlot is a function that makes a live plot and printSerial is to read for COM4.
When I run

```
rc = call("start cmd /K " + cmdline, cwd=dir, shell=True)
```

my objective is to open a new command window and run that, once the two processes can't run in the same cmd. This works properly if I just run it, but when it is an exe it gives an error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dataCollection'
```

If someone thinks the rest of the code is relevant let me know, since it is a bit extensive I'm not posting it for now.
Thank you.